# Is there a way to keep the numbering of the bibliography but have the citation itself in apa-style?

Tags: latex, bibliography

So currently I have a bibliography consisting of:

[1] Firstname Lastname, Second Author. Interesting paper about something, volume 900. Science Paper, 2022.

However, I want to have this in APA-citation, i.e.

[1] Lastname, F., Author, S. (2022). Interesting paper about something, volume 900. Science Paper.

However, when implementing apacite, which is the answer that is most suggested from my google searches, this results in the removal of the [1], and the in-text references are ruined as well. Is there a way to keep these [x] references both in text and in the bibliography, but to get the citations there in APA-style?

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Rule of thumb: whenever you want to change something in your bib style, this is a lot easier if you switch to biblatex.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz How is this not a MRE? It should be pretty clear what I want here

Comment: I haven't seen a way to do this in biblatex either

Comment: A mre should include a short, but compilable document we can use for testing. We don't know how your document looks like, which package you use etc.

Answer (score 0):

With biblatex you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=numeric,bibstyle=apa]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibentrysetcount}{\mkbibparens{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{angenendt}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted:)